# The Binding of Isaac not working(Missing Executable)

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac, the-binding-of-isaac-afterbirth

[image: This is what it looks like]I asked this question months ago, but no one answered a good answer. So I'm posting it again. And keep in mind mods that this should not be flagged as a similar question to other existing ones as I, over the course of months, tried all of them. So! Here's my problem.

So this happened about a year ago. I just boot up Isaac like normal, and it's missing an executable. This is no big deal. I delete the game, reinstall it, and it still doesn't work. I tried whitelisting the entire steam folder from all of my antiviruses(V3 Lite and Comodo Antivirus). And then I noticed something peculiar: the game doesn't really install. Upon checking the download hub, I found the game stalled at about 95% of downloading, then flags it as a "canceled update", although the download says 573/573 downloaded. And sometimes when the game somehow installs seemingly randomly, it gives me the missing execution error. I checked the game files, and everything like the DLLs and data are there, but no exe. The shortcut on my pc screen also gives the exact some error. any help?
EDIT: Keep in mind upon attempting to download the game again, it briefly says download completed before it saying it was canceled, if this matters.

Comment: The correct way to get an answer on an unanswered question is to post a bounty on it, not to post a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

From [this link](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=8676-EFLX-7453) here's what seems to be the best course of action.

- Check your anti-virus. This error is most commonly seen when your anti-virus software mistakenly reports game files as malicious and quarantines them.

There are a couple of ways to resolve this:

1. Within the anti-virus software look for game files that have been reported and mark them as safe
2. Set your anti-virus software to Game Mode
3. Have the anti-virus software exclude that game folder when it scans for malicious content.

-
 - Verify the game files / Make sure that all of the files are installed. To do that
   1. Restart your computer and launch Steam
   2. From the Library section, right-click on the game and select Properties from the menu.
   3. Select the Local files tab and click the Verify integrity of game files... button.
   4. Steam will verify the game's files - this process may take several minutes.

[Source](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=2037-QEUH-3335)

If all of this fails your last option is to

- Submit a support ticket. You can do that [here](https://help.steampowered.com/en/).